# merging structured encrypted data

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

this is a followup of the post I made there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428690/merging-structured-encrypted-data

Essentialy, I'd like to know if there is a way to merge bencoded data (or otherwise structured data), encrypted.

i.e. you have something like this

```
{
   "comment": "Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version"
}
```

which bencoded looks like this

```
bencode1 = "d7:comment33:Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower versione"
```

You encrypt this, with I am not too sure what, or even if this kind of cryptography exists.
You get some encrypted content, let's call it

```
encrypted1 = encrypt(bencode1)
```

From somewhere else, you get

```
encrypted2 = encrypt(bencoded2)
```

You don't know what bencoded2 is, just the encrypted result of it.

Somehow, I'd like to know if there is way to get:

```
encrypted_merge = merge(encrypted1,encrypted2)
```

Having myself the decrypt function/keys, I would be able to do

```
merge_result = decrypt(encrypted_merge)
```

which would show me that the the merge result, decrypted is

```
{
   "comment": "This comment was updated somehow during the merge",
   "new_key": "this new key got added during the merge"
}
```

I am not too sure if that is very clear, but I am mostly interested if this kind of encryption exists, and if yes, what words I should look online.

From my previous post, "Homomorphic encryption" could be a way, but I am still pretty far from knowing if it is indeed a way or not, or if it depends on the content stored, or would require exposing a lot of metadata.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the constraints? Who got the key who can access the key? What does prevent you from decrypting and merging than encrypting?

Comment: Alice has 2 devices: Alice1 and Alice2.
Both devices wants to keep some content up to date on the server side. 
Currently, the only way to do this is that anytime Alice1 pushes a change (bencoded data, encrypted), both device get the update, decrypt it, and merge it locally. One of them can then push the resulting encrypted merged data on the server.
I'd like to know if that merge can happen on the server side, with the data kept encrypted.
Alice1 and Alice2 are the only one having the private key to decrypt the content.

Comment: Let Alice and Bob have public-private key that they can use to exchange DHKE ( not ephemeral) and then use HKDF after the derive a key. Use this key to update where bots sides can have the same key.

Comment: I'm not sure why that waskally wabbit disappeared in the final merged result. I do see an issue in the fact that the final result isn't a simple concat if you also take care of the braces surrounding the text.